# Spherical Harmonics expansion of a Dirac Delta at the North Pole

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-harmonics

I think all the coefficients for the spherical harmonic expansion of a delta function at the north pole should be a constant (presumably 1), but I'm having difficulties calculating them. Could someone kindly take some time showing me how they are calculated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why they all have to be 1.  A difficulty with the North pole is that the usual coordinate system has a singularity there.  So think about a function that approximates the delta function, maybe something constant in a small radius around the North pole.

I'm using the definitions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Orthogonality_and_normalization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system (I think we are using the "physics" version of spherical coordinates.)

It seems to me that the $f_l^m$ coefficients should be zero whenever $m \ne 0$, because you are integrating $e^{im\varphi}$ from $\varphi=0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen for your reply. Yes, I agree that all the $f_l^m$ should be 0 if m is not 0, what I meant in the original post should be $f_l^0$ are a constant regardless of l, which is equivalent to the Fourier Transform results of a Delta function in time-frequency space. Do you know how to calculate the coefficients when m is indeed 0, eg. $f_2^0$, $f_4^0$ etc?

Comment: Try approximating the delta function by $f(\theta,\varphi) = (\pi \epsilon^2)^{-1} I_{\theta\in[0,\epsilon]}$ and let $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: And the Legendre polynomials will be approximately $1$ there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomial#Recursive_definition (look at the graphs).  So all you pick up is the $\sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}}$.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, this has really solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come around this, and the integration should be:
$$C_{lm}=\int_\Omega\delta(0,0)Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi) d\Omega =Y_{lm}^*(0,0).$$
This can be generalised to any impulse function at angles $(\theta_0, \phi_0)$, and the results will simply be $Y_{lm}^*(\theta_0, \phi_0)$.